# using pandas to read a csv file with whatever columns matchi with the column names given in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple CSV files with about 15 columns. I am interested only in 5 columns. So I stored them in a list.

```
mylist=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
```

I read the csv file in pandas dataframe df.

Now when I do df[mylist] it throws error because `col4` is not present in the csv file.

My question is how do I still read the files even if some of columns listed in my list are not present in the csv.

Example: if csv file doesn't have `col4`, then the code should just extract whatever columns are matching with the columns in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) of real columns names with `list`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df1 = df[df.columns.intersection([mylist])]
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col in your_list]
df = df[cols]
```